# STM32 floating point number calculation error

Tags: c, stm32, floating

I have to perform a calculation with 2 floating point numbers using measurements taken from a distance sensor with STM32. Calculation is carried out by following equation;

> result = (df-ds)/ds*10000;

where df is first measurement and ds is second measurement.

Sample values for equation;

> df = 26.6810;
>   ds = 25.3270;

My problem is, STM32's result for these values is **534.578247**, but when i do calculation on Windows' calculator manually i get the result of **534.607336** which is quite different from STM32's calculation. I've also used one hand-calculator and hand-calculator is giving out exactly same result with the computer.

All variables are declared as floats in the program.
Why is there so much difference between two calculations?
What kind of changes i could make to make STM32 give more precise results?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT :** The code i am using as follows;

```
 float result= 0;
 dmbres = 27.4587;
   int main()
   {
   while(1)
   {
   result= (float)((dmbres- res)/res)*10000;
   dmbres = res;
   sprintf(datapackage, "%d;%.4f;%.6f\r\n", mid, res,result);
   monitor(datapackage);
   }
```

**datapackage** consists 2 other information i need from MCU and they are not relevant with the **result** calculation.

I am using STM32F407 DISC-1 board.

Comment: What's the C code? I think we can't understand the problem without seeing the code that generates your issue.

Comment: `26.6810` is not a float, it's a double. Which STM32 is this, does it have a FPU? Overall, there's way too little information to answer the question. Post the actual code.

Comment: `df` and `ds` are too close in magnitude for the subtraction to have an effect on the 4th significant figure. The issue is in code you haven't pasted up.

Comment: I added the code. Thank you for your attention

Comment: With the precision of the numbers you have posted, the result could be anywhere between 534.566797 and 534.647875, so your actual result looks fine to me.

Comment: @IanAbbott But how could the computer and hand-calculator gives out exactly same results but not STM32?

Comment: @TeoLaferla I am assuming that `df` could be anywhere in the range (26.68095, 26.68105) and that `ds` could be anywhere in the range (25.32695, 25.32705) since your `sprintf` rounds their displayed value to 4 decimal places.

Comment: I read the FPU manual of your MCU, but I've no time to indagate. Have you enabled "correctly" the FPU? https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/55689-102-1-276747/STMicroelectronics.User_Manual_2.pdf

Comment: @SirJoBlack I checked several similar threads on here, they all say FPU is initialized by declaring a variable `float`. So i didn't do anything about that and honestly i don't know how.

Comment: @TeoLaferla, Have you tried with a `double`. However I think the C compiler (or better the MCU libraries) should take in account FPU initializations.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the manual I indicate you above at page 240. There's some interesting C code.

Comment: @SirJoBlack Yes i did try `double` and can't say results between computer calculation and MCU calculation came closer.

Comment: The FPU is single precision 32 bit, then `float`.

Comment: How does the 27.4587 in your code sample relate to 26.6810 or 25.3270.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following code:

```
 float result= 0;
 dmbres = 27.4587;
   int main()
   {
   while(1)
   {
   result= (float)((dmbres- res)/res)*10000;
   dmbres = res;
   sprintf(datapackage, "%d;%.4f;%.6f\r\n", mid, res,result);
   monitor(datapackage);
   }
```

And you gave the following equation:

> result = (df-ds)/ds*10000;

with the values:

> df = 26.6810; ds = 25.3270;

And you reported the following result:

> result = 534.578247

I assume the following:

1. The value shown for `df` (**26.6810**) came from the conversion of the variable `res` to a string by:

   ```
   sprintf(datapackage, "%d;%.4f;%.6f\r\n", mid, res,result);
   ```

   Since this output string is being rounded to 4 decimal places, the `float res` value it came from could have been any value in the range **26.680950164794921875** to **26.6810474395751953125**. This forms the `dmbres` value for the next iteration of the loop.
2. The value shown for `ds` (**25.3270**) came from the conversion of the variable `res` to a string in the next iteration of the loop.  Since this output string is also being rounded to 4 decimal places, the `float res` value it came from could have been any value in the range **25.3269500732421875** to **25.3270473480224609375**).
3. The value shown for `result` (**534.578247**) came from the conversion of the variable `result` to a string by

   ```
   sprintf(datapackage, "%d;%.4f;%.6f\r\n", mid, res,result);
   ```

   This output string is very precise for a `float`. The closest stored value is **534.5782470703125**.

For the possible values of `df` and `ds`, the smallest possible value for `result = (df-ds)/ds*10000` is given by **(26.680950164794921875 - 25.3270473480224609375) / 25.3270473480224609375 * 10000**, and the largest possible value is given by **(26.6810474395751953125 - 25.3269500732421875) / 25.3269500732421875 * 10000**.

The closest `float` values resulting from those two expressions are **534.5679931640625** and **534.6468505859375**, respectively. Your actual result of **534.5782470703125** falls within this range, so is not unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the numbers are "too close". 32-bit float uses 23 bits for the significant so it is only about 7 significant decimal digits. e.g. 1234567. You can place the decimal point anywhere but any digits beyond the 7 is imprecise, especially once you perform calculations with them. 64-bit double uses 52 bits and holds about 16 decimal digits.

So you can declare the variables as double. That would give you a greater range of precision, at a cost of (much) slower execution.